# How to configure CNAMES to be part of a WordPress Network

Tags: multisite, subdomains, network-admin

Is it possible to have a network setup based on CNAME? I know that WordPress networks handle sub-directory structures in the a network quite nicely, but I am wondering if I can do the same with with CNAMES.

For example, can I set one of my WP networks to house these 2 sites (thus giving me the ability to share plugins and themes):

- www.example.com
- dev.example.com

Comment: [have you read this?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Types_of_multisite_network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you are mixing up the terms of CNAMES and subdomains a bit.

In case you are looking for a subdomain setup for WordPress Multisite: Yes this [is possible](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Types_of_multisite_network):

> The sites in a network have different URLs. You can choose one of two
>   ways for the URL to specify the site:
>
> -Each site has a different *subdomain*. For example: `site1.example.com, site2.example.com`.
>
> -Each site has a different *path*. For example: `example.com/site1, example.com/site2`

Comment: sorry @kraftner -- I am often times working on both sides of the fence. When in DNS Management the `www` part or `site1` part is referred to as a CNAME. When in WP Multisite, I guess it's referred to as `subdomain`. Thanks for answering.

Comment: So let me ask this @kraftner -- can you have one of your networks configured as `www.example.com` & `dev.example.com` while a different network configured as `example.com/subdir1` & `example.com/subdir2` at the same time and in the sane WordPress installation?

Comment: This is a no, not possible. Also for the future: Please add such things as an edit to the question or open a new question if id deviates from the original question too much. Comments are too easily overlooked.